# Empty space on top of toolbar. Android, Java

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I just included an options menu in my app, but in one of my activities it seems to create a white empty space- can anyone tell me why??
It work in other activities in the same app, but not this single activity.
I Hope anyone can help :-)

```
public class GifsActivity extends OptionsMenu {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gifs);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView gifImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_gif);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/Vth6CBz.gif")
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .into(gifImageView);
    }

}
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.examand1.GifsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_gif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Picture of the activity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `android:gravity="center_vertical"` from your layout. Then your layout will be as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include 
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@id/include"
        android:id="@+id/iv_gif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am happy to help you :). Please upvote and accept as an answer it will be helpful for others.

Comment: I couldn't get you?

Comment: Not yet, please do for the answer